# excel run-time error 1004 pivot table field name is not valid

Tags: excel, vba

Good day everyone!

I got run-time error 1004 pivot table field name is not valid in EXCEL

I have dynamic data range from *Infolog Data!R2C1:R3800C24* is valid, on 1 pc it work on other 3 pc dosent work, and I can't understand why...
Office 2013

```
Sub Creation_of_list_planning()


        Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
        Sheets("Planning").Delete           
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True   

        Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Planning"

End Sub
```

In debug I got error in this part:

```
Sub Creation_of_table()

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Infolog Data!R2C1:R3800C24",            Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:="Planning!R1C1", TableName:="Planning", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SourceData command is missing some apostrophes required due to the spaces in the sheet name:

```
SourceData:= _
"'Infolog Data'!R2C1:R3800C24"
```

There also needs to be a valid header in A2:X2 on that sheet.

Comment: table betin from R1C1 and header of table begin from R2C1 to R2C24

Comment: Sorry - I misread the start row. Did you make the change I suggested, and are there valid field names (so no blank cells for example) in A2:X2?

Comment: from range R2C1:R3800C24 was blank cells, for created table it clear list Planning, I have R1C1 for R1C16384 blank

Comment: Not what I asked, I'm afraid.

Comment: I have R1C1 for R1C16384 blank

Comment: then from R2C1 begin header and from R3C1 table

Comment: Let's try one step at a time. Did you add the change I mentioned?

Comment: yes but I got same error I change to:
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Infolog Data!R1C1:R3800C24", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Planning!R1C1", TableName:="Planning", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14

Comment: That's not changed. Do you have valid field names in **every** cell in the range R2C1:R2C24

Comment: manually from range Infolog Data!R1C1:R3800C24 got error from range Infolog Data!R2C1:R3800C24 all fine created....

Comment: Then I don't understand the error **if** you have now applied the change I suggested.

Comment: On my pc work without error on user pc got that error, bouth windows 7x32 office 13 same microsoft visual c`++ labory and net framework

Comment: 1. Did you actually apply the change I suggested? 2. Are you both using the same workbook?

Comment: Yes I delete 1 line from Source data list and set

Comment: Sub Planning_creation()

Range("S3:S100").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("P3:P100").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("S3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.Run "Additional_column_Infolog_Data"  
 
Application.Run "Creation_of_list_planning"  

Application.Run "Creation_of_table"           


End Sub
                
Sub Additional_column_Infolog_Data()

        Sheets("Infolog Data").Columns("E:E").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Columns("W:W").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: Sheets("Infolog Data").Columns("S:S").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Columns("X:X").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 
        Sheets("Infolog Data").Range("W2") = "Supplier Code2"
        Sheets("Infolog Data").Range("X2") = "Ïëàí âðåìÿ2"
  
 End Sub

Comment: Sub Creation_of_list_planning()


        Application.DisplayAlerts = False  
        Sheets("Planning").Delete          
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True   
        
        Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Planning"
End Sub
Sub Creation_of_table()
  ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Infolog Data!R1C1:R3800C24", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Planning!R1C1", TableName:="Planning", DefaultVersion:= _
        xlPivotTableVersion14

Comment: end sub                'thats all

Comment: You **still** haven't made the change I suggested.